# Property access restriction in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance

Trying to get the reason behind it.

Scenario#1

```
public class Customer
{
   string _name = "Ram";
   //now trying to assign some new value to _name on the next line 
   _name // this property is inaccessible on this line.
}
```

Scenario#2

```
public class BaseCustomer
{
   protected string _name;
}


public class DerivedCustomer : BaseCustomer 
{
   _name //inaccessible here

   public void SetName()
   {
     _name = "Shyam"; //accessible here
   }
}
```

Can somebody please let me know what is cause behind this??

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the line you have marked what you are actually trying to do is `_name = "Foo";`? If so it would make it a lot clearer to actually edit this into the question. As it is you have a bare variable without a terminating `;` which is not valid code in any context.

Comment: How do you infer the conclusion that it is "inaccessible"? The shown snippets are simply not valid C# Syntax.

Comment: @Fildor: Whenever I've heard pretty much any dev refer to something as "inaccessible", it means _"I can't find it in IntelliSense"_.

Comment: @Flater Yes - the downsides of comfortable IDEs ...

Answer (score 3):

Simple. You can't make variable assignments (without declaration) in the class context. You need to use a constructor to put the assignment in:

```
public class DerivedCustomer : BaseCustomer 
{
   public DerivedCustomer()
   {
       _name = "hello";
   }

   ...
}
```

... or put it in the declaration:

```
public class BaseCustomer
{
   protected string _name = "hello";
}
```

Comment: My question is what is the reason behind this??

Comment: @Kgn-web It doesn't make sense. When should such code be executed?

Answer (score 2):

*Note: Experts will probably find exceptions to my simplified explanation. I'm keeping it simple for the sake of explaining the key intention to OP.*

---

In a way, a class really only contains **declarations**. This can be a field:

```
public class Customer
{
    private string _name;
}
```

Or a property:

```
//Example 1 - Simple property
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//Example 2 - Publically gettable (but not settable) property with private field (which is settable)
public class Customer
{
    private string _name;          //this is a field
    public string Name => _name;   //this is a property that relies on the field
}
```

Or a method:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string GetName()
    {
          return "John";
    }
}
```

Boiling it down, I would summarize it as follows:

> A class **only contains** declarations of how it is structured: fields, properties, methods.
>
> A class **does not** directly contain code (i.e. logic which uses the fields/properties).
>
> However, a class' **method** or **property** can contain code (i.e. logic which uses the fields/properties), but this code is considered to be **part of the method/property**, not part of the class (directly).

---

What you're trying to do doesn't quite make sense to me. I'm not quite sure what you're hoping to achieve by trying to access the `_name` in those locations.

It only makes sense to reference this field in the locations where you can reference it:

- **In a method body** - If you need the field during the method's execution
- **In a property** - When the field is used during the set/get of a property
- **In a constructor** - To set the value of the field.

But you're trying to put in **in the class**. This raises many questions:

- What are you trying to do with `_name`?
- Assuming you could reference the field where you want to; when are you expecting this code to be executed?
- How would this be any different from simply using a method (or the constructor)?